# Postgres Update Limit

Tags: postgresql, database-design, postgresql-9.5

I'm curious if Postgres has anything in place where I could limit the amount of rows kept for a ID.

For example, say I have a users table and login_coordinates table. Every time the user logs in, the most current coordinates get fed to a column in the users table, as well as inserting into the login_coordinates table.

I only want to keep the last 10 records, and deleting the 11th(oldest) record in the login_coordinates table for all users.

Users

```
   user_id            | current_coordinates        |    
----------------------+----------------------------+
    1                 | aaaa.bbbbb, aaaaa.bbbbbb   |    
    2                 | zzzz.xxxxxx, xxxxx.xxxcxx  |    
    3                 | dddd.xxxxxx, xxxxx.xxxcxx  |
```

Login Coordinates

```
  coordinates_id      | old_login_coordinates      |        user_id           |
----------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+
    1                 | aaaa.bbbbb, aaaaa.bbbbbb   |     1                    |
    2                 | xxxxx.xxxxxx, xxxxx.xxxcxx |     1                    |
    3                 | xxxxx.xxxxxx, xxxxx.xxxcxx |     1                    |
```

Is there anything that would limit the records to 10 coordinate_id per user, always deleting the oldest records?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5.

Comment: Please *always* declare your version of Postgres. Also essential here: do you have concurrent write access? Can a user log in multiple times at once or is this impossible?

Comment: Concurrent write access will be allowed, but we will be doing row locks, and the likelihood of concurrent writes will be low as the main system is primarily read only. A user can login multiple times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> as well as inserting into the login_coordinates table

I don't see the benefit of redundant storage. Just write to the table `login_coordinates`. Easy enough to access with only 10 rows per user. Don't update the user row as well.

Basically, what @Ziggy already suggested, with more flesh. Based on this table:

```
CREATE TABLE login_coordinates (
  login_coordinates_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, user_id integer NOT NULL  -- REFERENCES users
, login_at timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
, coordinates point NOT NULL
);
```

Using `OFFSET 9 LIMIT 1` to pick nr. 10:

```
DELETE FROM login_coordinates lc
WHERE  login_at <= (
   SELECT login_at
   FROM   login_coordinates
   WHERE  user_id = lc.user_id
   ORDER  BY login_at DESC
   OFFSET 9  -- only found if at least 10 rows present
   LIMIT  1
   )
AND    user_id = 1;

INSERT INTO login_coordinates (user_id, coordinates)
VALUES (1, '(1, 2)');
```

Comment: Redundant storage is mostly for auditing purpose. We don't want to fill our users table with auditing information like time and place of past logins. When a user logs in, we will be keeping the most recent login in the users table, along with a json web token. For auditing, we will keep the last 9 + current login (10 total) in a separate table. We will allow multiple logins, but limit that based on location (3 total).

Comment: @unseen_damage: But: `A user can login multiple times.` If each login updates the row in `users`, I see concurrency trouble ahead. The current session might consider the login of a later session with the same user as its own. Etc.

Comment: Unless I have implemented this wrong, the above query deletes all entries after #10 is entered in. Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: @unseen_damage: Sorry, that was an error on my side. Sort order must be descending to get the "oldest" timestamp. Consider the fixed query.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement an ON INSERT trigger and delete, for the same user, any rows with a timestamp older than the oldest (MIN) of a subselect ordered by timestamp DESC limit 10.

#### Edit, using an array in users:

An alternative is using an array straight in the users table:

Add a type and a new array in users:

```
CREATE TYPE past_logon AS (login_at timestamptz, coordinates point);
ALTER TABLE users ADD past_logons past_logon[];
```

This can be added to the function that handles the logon (replace `point(1,1)` and `= 1` with point and user in logon function parameters)

```
UPDATE users SET
  past_logons = (now(), point(1,1))::past_logon || past_logons[1:9]
WHERE user_id = 1;
```

Example for retrieving the list of past logons from the array

```
SELECT u.user_id, pl.*
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN LATERAL unnest(u.past_logons) pl ON true
ORDER BY pl.login_at;
```

Comment: Edited the answer to include an example using an array instead of another table for purposes like this.